# Set export quality in Photoshop Touch

Tags: photos, images, editing

I'm *pretty* satisfied with Adobe Photoshop Touch but am struggling with my export file sizes. As far as I can tell there is no way to adjust the **quality** or **file size** of your exported JPG. The only way I have found to control my exported file's size is to reduce the image size.

This seems like a rather large functionality oversight...